# Create dynamic cards Ionic v2 from firebase

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am trying to create dynamically ionic cards from my firebase database. I am using ngFor, but each card contains a series of buttons. When I create the cards they all get all the available buttons. How can I condition them in a way that they only get create the buttons that are linked to them? Or is there a better way of doing this?

**Ts**

```
databaseRef.on("child_added",(snapshot)=>{
  var cat=snapshot.child("Name").val();
  var icon=snapshot.child("Icon").val();
  this.types.push({
    title: cat,
    icon: icon
  });
  var cardLists= document.getElementsByClassName("cardList");

  console.log(cardLists.namedItem); 
  databaseRef2=database.ref().child("Catalogos").child(cat).child("SubCatalogos");
  databaseRef2.on("child_added",(snapshot)=>{
    var sub=snapshot.child("Name").val();
    var icn=snapshot.child("Icon").val();
    var owner=snapshot.child("Owner").val();
    console.log(cat);
    console.log(owner);
    this.generes.push({
      title:sub,
      icon:icn,
      Owner:owner,
      previous:cat
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-card   *ngFor="let item of types" >
<ion-card-header color="light">
  {{item.title}}
  <ion-icon name="{{item.icon}}"></ion-icon>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button color='light' clear>
      <ion-icon name='brush'></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button color="light" clear (click)="presentPrompt2(item)" >
      <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-list id="cardList" >
  <button ion-item class="SubCards" *ngFor="let item of generes" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
    <ion-icon name="{{item.icon}}"  item-left></ion-icon>
    {{item.title}}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

**JSON structure**

```
"Catalogos" : {
"Books" : {
  "Icon" : "book",
  "Name" : "Books",
  "SubCatalogos" : {
    "Comedy" : {
      "Icon" : "happy",
      "Name" : "Comedy",
      "Owner" : "Books"
    }
  }
},
"Magazines" : {
  "Icon" : "book",
  "Name" : "Magazines",
  "SubCatalogos" : {
    "Horror" : {
      "Icon" : "book",
      "Name" : "Horror",
      "Owner" : "Magazines"
    }
  }
}
}
```

(If I create the everything using createElement() and make everything myself it works, however no cards show up at all)
Full code in the link [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0tF4r9gp4ljTnM2UC1yaTZZV0E?usp=sharing)

Comment: you could check if the card need all buttons with a boolean. In example Button 1 have isneeded=false; Then before you create the Card you can check with ngIf if this boolean is true. If its not true set the button "invisible" and if its true set the button to "visible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem, what I did was nest inside the first for an ngIf to verify if the names matched, Inside that ngIf I nested the other For. Also I changed the JSON, I took out all the SubCatalog and made it a separate node and added a "Parent" key to each one pointing to the catalog it belonged to.